# Is it correct to use 'against of' in the following sentence?

Tags: phrases

Please read the following sentences.

> 1) We are against of removing our resource when there is no work.
>
> 2)  We are against removing our resource when there is no work.

Which sentence is correct?

Also: I think 'sacking' is not a polite word. Am I right?

Thanks,

Comment: You're asking two questions. Since they are completely unrelated, you should make a separate question for "Is 'sacking' a polite word"?

Answer (score 2):

*against* is itself a preposition like *of*, so it does not require any more preposition after it.

Moreover, *[against](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/against?q=against)* means

> in opposition to

which includes the preposition *to*, so that the required meaning is already achieved.

> We are against <strike>of</strike> removing our resource when there is no work.

Answer (score 0):

The second usage is correct.

An even better expression might be "We are opposed to removing ..."

I would also suggest that you probably mean resources rather than resource - it seems unlikely that you only have 1 resource - even 1 worker is plural as you are referring to a plurality of that worker over time.

"Sacking" meaning "ending the employment of" is not generally polite. The accepted euphemisms include:

- Terminating (employment ... not life) - a legally acceptable term with no connotations
- Making redundant - implying that the worker was surplus to requirements
- Letting go - could mean anything
- Dismissing - implies misconduct on the part of the worker
- Sacking - ditto
- Firing - ditto
- Allowing more family-time - just silly.